# Optimization by bobyqa lower and upper bound mix as output

Tags: arrays, windows, r, output

I try to estimate the maximum log liklihood of a function (f(x)). I am sorry that I cannot post the whole function since it is very long and painful to go trought. The goal is to optimize the function according to x where x is an array like x = c(x[1],..,x[7]) in addition there are several loops inside with differnet parameters. However I testet this function by using several input parameters and it seems to work fine. (No errors ect.)

To maximize the function I use:

```
library('nloptr')
bobyqa(c(0.3, 0.3, 1,70, 0.005, 0.02,70), Log.Likelihoodsum, lower = c(0.01, 0.01, 1,4, 0.001, 0.001,4), upper = c(0.6, 0.6, 1,90, 0.01, 0.1,90),control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-7))
```

The problem comes now with the output:

```
> bobyqa(c(0.3, 0.3, 1,70, 0.005, 0.02,70), Log.Likelihoodsum, lower = c(0.01, 0.01, 1,4, 0.001, 0.001,4), upper = c(0.6, 0.6, 1,90, 0.01, 0.1,90),control = list(xtol_rel = 1e-7)) #Function explodes for some values, i.e. 1000 oder mu oder sigma..
$par
[1] 0.600 0.600 1.000 4.000 0.001 0.100 4.000

$value
[1] 1.210564

$iter
[1] 113

$convergence
[1] 4

$message
[1] "NLOPT_XTOL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because xtol_rel or xtol_abs (above) was reached."
```

As you can see, the "optimal" parameters are a mixture of the upper and lower bound. Does anyone have an idea how I can proceed? Do I make a fundamentel error that you can see from this description?

btw: I tested the function by inserting the lower upper and sart levels and a got higher value for the start array, a lower one for the upper and a higher for the lower array. Why it does not just give me the start array as an output? (since the value is higher than the actual output)

Would really appreaciate any help..

thx

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided the function I can't comment on that but the phenomenon you observe can easily be seen in a simple example.

Consider minimizing f(x) = x subject to 0 <= x <= 1.  Clearly the minimum is 0 and if we make the lower bound less then the minimum will be less too.  Whatever we set the lower bound to will be the minimum.

```
> for(lower in c(0, -1, -100)) 
+   print(bobyqa(1, identity, lower = lower, upper = 1)$par)
[1] 0
[1] -1
[1] -100
```

**Added**

Note that 1 is both the lower and upper bound for the third parameter.  Its possible that the algorithm can't handle that.  Try removing that from the parameters and set it to 1 in the function itself.

Another thing to do is create a grid and evaluate the objective at each point.  Removing the third parameter as just discussed create a grid `g` and evaluate the objective function `f` at each point. We have assumed that the objective function is of the form f(x) where x is the vector of 6 parameters.

```
lower <- c(0.01, 0.01, 4, 0.001, 0.001,4)
upper <- c(0.6, 0.6, 90, 0.01, 0.1,90)

# pick 5 values of each parameter from lower to upper
m <- mapply(seq, lower, upper, MoreArgs = list(length = 5), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
g <- do.call(expand.grid, m)  # g will have 5^6 rows & 6 cols
v <- apply(g, 1, f)
g[which.min(v), ]
```

Now use that as your answer if you don't need anything too precise or if you want something better then use it as a starting value.

Comment: As I wrote, the start value provides already a larger value than the lower boundarie. the output is a mixture of lower and upper bound. By only using the lower bound or the upper bound i get "better" values.

The code is just to long and I dont think that someone would like to go trough it.

Comment: The starting point is not infeasable, why do you think so? since the starting point is a local minimum and since this local minimum is larger/smaller then the found parameters I do not understand why the algo did not gave me the starting values back. 
Any chance of contacting you private? (I am desp. looking for some help (not for free))

Comment: I tried diffrent algos and different staring values but the result doesnt change much (sometimes i get 20.0000232 instead of 20 as a start value)
I would appreaciate if somebody could go trought the code. (would probably take some 3-4 hours) I be willing to give 30 an hour. thx (rhelpthesis at outlook dot com)

Comment: I have added some additional things for you to try in the answer.